# call a function from from one python class to another which are at different directories

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

i need to call a function from from one python class to another which are at different directories.
I'm using Eclipse and PyDev for developing scripts.

sample.py

```
class Employee:
 def meth1(self,arg):
        self.arg=arg
        print(arg)

ob=Employee()
ob.meth1("world")
```

main.py

```
class main:
    def meth(self,arg):
        self.arg=arg
        print(arg)


obj1=main()
obj1.meth("hello")
```

I need to access **meth1** in **main.py**

**updated code**

```
main.py
from samp.sample import Employee
class main:
    def meth(self,arg):
        self.arg=arg
        print(arg)


obj1=main()


obj1.meth("hello")
```

After executing **main.py** it is printing "world" automatically without calling it.

my requirement is i need to call **meth1** from **main.py** **explicitly**

please find my folder below
[image: Eclipse folder hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

`import` is the concept you need here. `main.py` will need to `import sample` and then access  symbols defined in that module such as `sample.Employee`

To ensure that `sample.py` can be found at import time, the path to its parent directory can be appended to `sys.path` (to get access to that, of course, you will first need to `import sys`). To manipulate paths (for example, to turn a relative path like `'../samp'` into an absolute path, you might want to `import os` as well and take a look at the standard library functions  the sub-module `os.path` has to offer.

Comment: just as you said i added import statement in main.py and "__init__ in each directory" **from samp.sample import  ob** when i executed main.py the output is "world" "hello" i mean "world" is displayed automatically

Comment: @Sid the first time you `import` a file, the code in it will be executed, like your `ob=Employee()` etc. if you want to defer execution of those lines, tidy them away into a function which you'll then call only when needed.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to import the sample.py file as a module to your main.py file. Since the files are in different directories, you will need to use the [`__init__.py`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

From the documentation:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.

Here is a [related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path) which explains the solution in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

It's generally not a good idea to alter the `sys.path` variable. This can make scripts non-portable. Better is to just place your extra modules in the user site directory. You can find out what that is with the following script.

```
import os
import sys
import site

print(os.path.join(site.USER_BASE, "lib", "python{}.{}".format(*sys.version_info[0:2]), "site-packages"))
```

Place your modules there. Then you can just import as any other module.

```
import sample

emp = sample.Employee()
```

Later you can package it using `distutils` or `setuptools` and the imports will still work the same.